# Error with my class default constructor

Tags: c++

I have a class which sets up some variables to another class, but i cannot seem to get it work as i get an error.

So i have this:

---

```
MainMenu::MainMenu(std::map<std::string,std::string>& theme){ 
    CreateSprite Background(theme["Background"]);
}

void create(sf::RenderWindow& output){
    output.draw( Background.callback() );
}
```

The header for it:

---

```
class MainMenu
{
private:

CreateSprite Background;

public:
MainMenu(std::map<std::string, std::string>&);
void create(sf::RenderWindow&);

};
```

The problem is I get:

`error C2512: 'CreateSprite' : no appropriate default constructor available`

My class for `CreateSprite` is set like this:

---

```
CreateSprite::CreateSprite(std::string& imagefile) {

if(!image.loadFromFile(imagefile)){
    exit(2);
}

sprite = sf::Sprite(image);
}

sf::Sprite CreateSprite::callback(){
return sprite;
}
```

The related `header` for this class is:

---

```
class CreateSprite
{
public:

CreateSprite(std::string&);
sf::Sprite callback();

private:

sf::Texture image;
sf::Sprite  sprite;

};
```

What have i got incorrect ?

Comment: Which line is the error message indicating?

Comment: `MainMenu::MainMenu(std::map<std::string,std::string>& theme){` this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your `MainMenu` has a member `Background` declared already, you should init it from member initializer:
change from

```
MainMenu::MainMenu(std::map<std::string,std::string>& theme){ 
    CreateSprite Background(theme["Background"]);
}
```

to

```
MainMenu::MainMenu(std::map<std::string,std::string>& theme)
:Background(theme["Background"])
{     
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i updated that but still get 
`error C2512: 'CreateSprite' : no appropriate default constructor available` it seems to be related to the curly braces =/ Unless all relevant functions now go in the braces rather than outside of them?

Comment: did you remove `CreateSprite Background(theme["Background"]);` from curly braces?

Comment: It looks like this now: http://i49.tinypic.com/4hpqox.jpg (i also updated my question to show MainMenu header file).

Comment: It produced new errors which are probably best for a new question which im about to post :)